# Select parent node with conditions in multiple children at unknown levels

Tags: xpath

In XPath, how to select the `id` of all `<a>` nodes that contain `x=10` and `y=100` in their children (which are at different levels)?

```
<root>
    <a id="1">
        <c>
            <x>10</x>
            <y>100</y>
        </c>
    </a>
    <a id="4">
        <c>
            <c>
                <x>10</x>
                <y>100</y>
            </c>
        </c>
    </a>    
    <a id="6">
        <x>20</x>
        <y>200</y>
    </a>
    <a id="7">
        <x>10</x>
        <y>300</y>
    </a>
</root>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this, I would imagine:

```
//a[.//x=10][.//y=100]/@id
```

Comment: @Orion Note that you should accept this answer (click the green checkmark) if it solved your problem.